# getElementbyId is returning null when window location is switched but an element with that Id definitely exists

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this code:

```
window.location.href = "orderConfirmation.html";

document.onload = orderConfirmation(); // I have tried to use window.onload as well

function orderConfirmation () {

    document.getElementById("test").innerText = "test" // This should make the p element have a body of "test"
}
```

In my orderConfirmation.html I have a paragraph element with an id of "test"

I know its not a spelling error or anything like that.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The parenthesis are causing your listener to fire when it registers. Try `document.onload = orderConfirmation`. Or use the more modern listener: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // put your code here })`

Comment: `window.location.href = "orderConfirmation.html";` will cause the currently loaded page to be unloaded and the new document to be loaded. Since you have that code before the event registration, the first thing that will happen is navigation. This means that the JavaScript on the first page won't be present on the second and therefore nothing will happen.